# Crontab does not work

Tags: script, cron

I am trying to run either at boot or at intervals of 5 min (everytime basically) a command that enables me to use my remote control.

Thus `sudo crontab -e -u root`, I add in crontab the following line:

```
*/5 * * * * sudo ir-keytable -a /etc/rc_maps_cfg -s rc0
@reboot sudo ir-keytable -a /etc/rc_maps_cfg -s rc0
```

and the command does not work. Bear in mind it works when I run it via terminal as per usual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to use sudo within the root crontab.

Give the full path to the commands in the crontab.